# C++ application crash when trying to read registry subkey

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a programme that should return the Value of a registry subkey. I tried this code:

```
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
HKEY regkey;
char out[255];
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sk, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &regkey);
RegGetValue(regkey, L"test", NULL, RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&out, (LPDWORD) strlen(out) +1);
RegCloseKey(regkey);
MessageBox(NULL, (LP) out, L"Output", MB_OK);
```

I wrote this in Visual Studio 2017 and it doesn't show any errors. But when I run it, it crashes on line 5.

Crash reason:

> Exception Error on 0x7511C481 (KernelBase.dll) in reader.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation While Reading at Location 0x00000005. (Translated by Google Translate)

I have already checked if `RegOpenKeyEx()` works and yes it does work.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Does `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeed?

Comment: For one thing, you are not checking if any of those function calls actually succeeded.

Comment: Yes `RegOpenKeyEx()` succeeded.

Comment: `&out` -- Why are you passing the address of a pointer?  This probably has nothing to do with reading the registry, and everything to do with not being aware of how to pass a pointer to a buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `sizeof(out)` and not `strlen(out)+1`. That variable is uninitizlied and depending on how you build this can either be filled with zeros (in which case you're telling `RegGetValue()` it can write 1 bytes into it) or it can have random data (in which case you're telling `RegGetValue()` it can write a random number of bytes).

The second issue is that `RegOpenKeyEx()` is called with `KEY_SET_VALUE` so you don't even have permission to read. You need `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`.

The third issue, and the one probably causing the crash, is that you cast the result of `strlen(out)+1` to a pointer. It's a number, not a pointer. The function is expecting a pointer so it can write the number of bytes it actually read. Use:

```
DWORD len = sizeof(out);
RegGetValue(regkey, L"test", NULL, RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&out, &len);
```

And finally, as all the comments mention, you should check for errors on all functions and handle all of them.

Comment: That `&out` seems wrong also.  It should be just `out`.

Comment: It should work in this case. Both `out` and `&out` point to the same thing for arrays. -- https://repl.it/OCKl/0